# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified when Gridview Editing

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

When I click to edit the txtHours box, I get this error when I click the submit button:

> Procedure or function UpdateWish has too many arguments specified.

I'm fairly new to all this so I've probably made a simple error somewhere. It's code which was written for me and I have changed it for a different application. Should all work if I can sort this error. I use ASP.NET, VB.Net and SQL Server. There is no code in the VB file which should affect this so I haven't included that. Any help appreciated.

FRONT END

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWishText" runat="server" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; text-align:center;" Columns="5" MaxLength="5" Font-Size="Large" Height="28px" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSubmitWish" runat="server" class="BackNextButton" style="margin-top:7px;" ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/submitButton.gif" ValidationGroup="Wish" />
<br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqdWish" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Enter Hours Worked" ValidationGroup="Wish" 
     CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="txtWishText" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
<h2 style="font-size:16px; color:#333333; font-family: 'Seymour One', sans-serif; text-align:center;">My Hours: <asp:Label ID="LabelTotalHours" runat="server" ></asp:Label></h2>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSMyWishes" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 
     DeleteCommand="RemoveWish" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
     SelectCommand="SelectFullWishesByAccount" 
     SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
     UpdateCommand="UpdateWish" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="wishID" Type="Int32" />
     </DeleteParameters>
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="name" DbType="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="wishID" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="dailyHours" Type="Decimal" />
     </UpdateParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>

 <asp:GridView ID="gdvMyWishes" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" DataSourceID="DSMyWishes" width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="wishID">

            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="wishText">
                    <ItemTemplate>                      
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelDate" font-size="1.0em"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dateInserted") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hours" SortExpression="wishText">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHours" runat="server" Columns="40" MaxLength="40" Text='<%# Bind("dailyHours") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" font-size="1.0em"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dailyHours") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Link"
            DeleteImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/deleteIcon.png" EditImageUrl="~/files/Images/icons/editIcon.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/files/Images/icons/submitIcon.png" CancelImageUrl="~/files/Images/icons/backIcon.png"/>
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                No hours recorded
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdateWish]
    @wishID     int,
    @dailyHours decimal(10,2)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE tblWishes
    SET dailyHours = @dailyHours
    WHERE wishID = @wishID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, it looks perfect for passing 2 update parameter and in stored procedure also there is 2 parameters.

Also for select and delete working fine with `CommandType.StoredProcedure`?

Otherwise, you should first try without stored procedure as per the following way.

- Removing `UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"` and set update query in `UpdateCommand`

Code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSMyWishes" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 
     DeleteCommand="RemoveWish" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
     SelectCommand="SelectFullWishesByAccount" 
     SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE tblWishes SET dailyHours = @dailyHours WHERE wishID = @wishID">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried it and the delete works fine. Edit doesn't cause that error anymore but it doesn't update dailyHours to what I change it to.